# Multer images array not store in mongoDB Database

Tags: mongodb, api, express, mongoose, multer

I am try to upload images on server and save image path in mongoDB database. but image path not stored in database `your text`

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: {type: String, required: true, trim: true },
email: {type:String, unique:true, required: true, trim: true, lowercase: true,
validate(value){
if(!validator.isEmail(value)){
throw new Error('Email is Invalid!')
}
}
},
password: {type: String, required:true, trim: true,minlength:7,
validate(value){
if(value.toLowerCase().includes('password')){
throw new Error('Password cannot conatin "password"')
}
}
},
age: {type: Number, required: true, default: 0,
validate(value) {
if(value \< 0) {
throw new Error('Age Must be a Postive number')
}
}
},
tokens: \[{
token: {
type: String,
required: true
}
}\],
avatar:{type: String}
}, {
timestamps: true
})
```

```
app.post('/users/me/avatar', authCheck, upload.array('avatar\[\]', 10), async (req,res,next)=\>{
console.log(req.file)
// const buffer = await shrap(req.file.path).resize({width:250,height:250}).png().toFile(req.file.destination, 'resized');
req.user.avatar = req.files.path,

    await req.user.save()
    res.status(200).send()

}, (error, req,res,next) =\>{
res.status(400).send({
error: error.message
})
})
```

I am try to upload images on server and save image path in mongoDb database. but image path not stored in database

Comment: Put your code in try catch for better error handling and debugging

Comment: Please be more specific, and tell us what worked and what didn't. because as for now all you did is post all of your code and tell us it doesn't work